# Python/ Openpyxl: How to pass a list to an if statement and make the cells bold if they contain any strings from the list value (MacOS)

Tags: python, openpyxl, string-formatting

I'm trying to make cells in column A bold if they contain any of the words in words(list) the code executes but nothing is happening in my final cells.

I've been styling the workbook with Openpyxl.

My code:

```
header_style = Font(bold = True)    
A = ws['A1':'A44']
words =  ['Assets', 'Current Assets', 'Liabilities' , 'Equity']
for words in A:    
     if cell.value == words:
            cell.font = header_style
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Many thanks!

Comment: Check whether the cells contain strings and use `in`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested on my side and here are the changes I made:

```
header_style = Font(bold = True)    
words =  ['Assets', 'Current Assets', 'Liabilities' , 'Equity']

wb = load_workbook(filename = 'test.xlsx')
ws = wb.active

# Get each cell of column A
for cell in ws['A']: 
    if cell.value in words:
            cell.font = header_style

wb.save('test.xlsx') // do not forget to save the file again
```

`if cell.value == words:` to `if cell.value in words:`

This don't check if value is in the words array. you have to replace `==` to `in`

And don't forget to save the file again with `wb.save('test.xlsx')`

Comment: Thank you Charlie and Kevin, such a simple mistake. I understand why it wasn't working with == as a list is an array hence the in.